# MySql: Inserting Data from Different Columns of Different Tables

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I would like to insert data using this given MySql query.

```
INSERT INTO `profitdb`(`BetID`, `PlayerID`, `PlayerWL`,`AgentID`,`AgentRisk`) 
SELECT `betdb`.`BetID`,`PlayerID`,`BetAmount` FROM `betdb`,
SELECT `agentdb`.`AgentID` FROM `agentdb`,
SELECT `agentdb`.`Risk` FROM `agentdb`
```

without the 3rd and 4th SELECT statement, its fine, but I would like to insert data of AgentID which will come from agentdb table, what is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: can you join this 2 tables ? there have common field?

Comment: you mean betdb and agentdb? I cant join these coz they dont have common field, btw I updated my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `union` your results, however, you are not `select`ing as many columns from `AgentID` and `Risk` as your `insert` command expects you to. You need to have as many columns as the `insert` expects you to have. Also, their type must match the expected type.

Comment: Oh I see, I'm not experienced in sql, so I just laid out my idea and asking what's the syntax, I tried what this site say, [http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/62086/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001361224.htm] and get the error #1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Comment: Exactly. You must make sure that your select is compatible with the insert.

Comment: I fixed the relations of tables and I used left joins in able to make the insert valid

Comment: So your insert is valid in syntax. Did you check whether the values inserted are the expected ones? If so, then your problem is solved. If my answer was helpful, then you can accept it, so in the future others will be helped by it as well.

Comment: Yes they are the expected ones. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `profitdb`(`BetID`, `PlayerID`, `PlayerWL`,`AgentID`) 
VALUES (SELECT `betdb`.`BetID`,`PlayerID`,`BetAmount` FROM `betdb`,
(SELECT `agentdb`.`AgentID` FROM `agentdb`))
```

Try the above one if it works.

Comment: sql says  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT `betdb`.`BetID`,`PlayerID`,`BetAmount` FROM `betdb`, (SELECT `agentdb`.`' at line 2

Comment: INSERT INTO `profitdb`(`BetID`, `PlayerID`, `PlayerWL`,`AgentID`) 
VALUES SELECT `betdb`.`BetID`,`PlayerID`,`BetAmount` FROM `betdb`,
(SELECT `agentdb`.`AgentID` FROM `agentdb`)
How about the above ?

Comment: One more idea is to take the column in vars and then use it in the insert statement.